# Is weak limit of redial sequence is radial?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, weak-convergence

Let $\{f_n\} \subset L^{2}(\mathbb R)$. Assume that $f_n \rightharpoonup g$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb R),$ (that is, $f_n$ converges to $g$ [weakly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)) in $L^2$), and $f_n(x)= f_n(-x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$  ($f_n$ is radial).

> Question: (1) Can we say $g$ is also a radial, that is, $g(-x)=g(x)$ for all $x$? What  about the higher dimension? (Counter example?)
>   (2) If $\|f_n-g\|_{L^2} \to 0$, can we say $g$ is radial?

Comment: As the limit is not unique (but only a.e. unique) you cannot hope for any property holding *for all* $x$.

Comment: @Jochen:Thanks. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Given a function $h$ denote by $\tilde h$ the function $\tilde h(x) = h(-x)$.

Suppose that $f_n \rightharpoonup g$. It isn't hard to see that $\tilde f_n \rightharpoonup \tilde g$ too. But $f_n = \tilde f_n$ so by the uniqueness of weak limits, $g = \tilde g$.

This equality needs to be interpreted correctly. It is not correct to say that $g(x) = g(-x)$ for all $x$ since functions in $L^2$ are only defined  almost everywhere, but rather that $g = \tilde g$ in $L^2$.